# Good hash algorithm for list of (memory) addresses

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have a list of (64-bit) addresses that represent a stack frame, and I want to hash these to a single 64-bit number to help identify those that have been seen before.  There are at most 128 addresses.

My current algorithm calculates the hash by iterating through the list, xor'ing each address into the hash and rotating the hash by 11 bits per cycle.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Why hash them at all and not just cast them to intptr_t (assuming C)?

Comment: I think he's trying to check program paths. He's trying to save a path of 64-bit addresses. The CRC64 answer seems good to me.

Comment: He wants to hash the whole list - I didn't get that, thanks for the clarification...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider some sort of [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Perhaps a [CRC64](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/259177/).

Comment: CRC should not be used as a hash, it has very bad collision behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of nice integer hash functions here, for both 32 and 64 bit:
http://www.concentric.net/~Ttwang/tech/inthash.htm

Also there's some written on it here: http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/evahash.html

Comment: The first link is now dead.  This https://gist.github.com/badboy/6267743 seems to be a saved copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't a problem you could try a cryptographic hash - truncate to how many bytes you want.